# Merging several columns with the same headers in R

Tags: r, pivot, spread

I have a data frame with several Participant_ID. For each Participant_ID, I have 4 variables (Start_day,End_day,Lights_out and Got_up) and 48 days for each variables (named here:...2 - ...3 - ...) :
[image]

I'd like to have 6 columns:
id- days - Start_day - End_day - Lights_out - Got_up

Basically, keep the "id" column and switch variables with days (...2, ...3,...4,...)

Does anyone know how to do that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly the problem can be solved within the `tidyverse` using the `pivot` functions from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# dummy data
df <- data.frame(id = c("ALM-M", "ALM-M", "ALM-M", "ALM-M"),
                 variable = c("Start day", "End day", "Lights out", "Got Up"),
                 col1 = c(44269, 44269, 4.1319, 0.3128),
                 col2 = c(44270, 44270, 0.1928, 0.4223))

# convert data (first make it longer, than wider)
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -c(id, variable), names_to = "cols", values_to = "vals") %>%
tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = variable, values_from = vals)


# A tibble: 2 x 6
  id    cols  `Start day` `End day` `Lights out` `Got Up`
  <chr> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1 ALM-M col1        44269     44269        4.13     0.313
2 ALM-M col2        44270     44270        0.193    0.422
```

[here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) you can find some more in depth explantion about the use of the `pivot` functions from the `tidyr` package.

Comment: Perfect!! It's  working perfectly!  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyr::pivot_longer` and `tidyr::pivot_wider`

**Example data**

```
dat<- tibble(id = 'participant_1',
             variables = c('Start_day','End_day','Lights_out', 'Got_up'),
             `...1`=c(0,1,2,3),
             `...2`=c(5,6,7,8),
             `...3`=c(0,1,2,3),
             `...4`=c(0,1,2,3))

# A tibble: 4 × 6
  id            variables   ...1  ...2  ...3  ...4
  <chr>         <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 participant_1 Start_day      0     5     0     0
2 participant_1 End_day        1     6     1     1
3 participant_1 Lights_out     2     7     2     2
4 participant_1 Got_up         3     8     3     3
```

**answer**

```
dat %>%
        pivot_longer(`...1`:`...4`) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = variables, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 4 × 6
  id            name  Start_day End_day Lights_out Got_up
  <chr>         <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 participant_1 ...1          0       1          2      3
2 participant_1 ...2          5       6          7      8
3 participant_1 ...3          0       1          2      3
4 participant_1 ...4          0       1          2      3
```